# Why a project manager isn't an entrepreneur?

Tags: organizational-structure

It's interesting for me to know the differences between a project manager and an entrepreneur?

Whet does an entrepreneur has that a project manager hasn't and why should a project manager work under an entrepreneur in the organization chart?

EDIT: If someone explains the key tasks of each one and the key differences i will get my answer!

Comment: Never heard of an entrepreneur  in the org chart. Unclear to me what you're getting at.

Comment: I'm afraid this question makes no sense to me.  Perhaps if you could explain what you think the two professions have in common?

Comment: In common parlance, an entrepreneur is the founder of a business venture or startup. What are you trying to understand that a dictionary definition or Wikipedia entry on the roles doesn't tell you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the definitions of each role.

[Entrepreneur:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/entrepreneur?s=t) *a person who organizes and manages any enterprise, especially a business, usually with considerable initiative and risk.*

[Project Manager:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_manager)  *[has] the responsibility of the planning, procurement and execution of a project, in any undertaking that has a defined scope, defined start and a defined finish.*

An entrepreneur can be a project manager, but not vice versa because the project manager is typically only risking assets of the company. Entrepreneurs will risk personal assets e.g., money, property, relationships, etc.

It's difficult to define the key tasks of each role because they differ depending on the industry and organization. I have had the experience of being both, and in both roles I've been required to have knowledge and skills of every position in the organization.

I will say that the defining factor for me is this: *time*.

As an entrepreneur, I spent every waking hour consumed by my business and obsessed with exceeding the venture's goals. When I was project manager, I clocked in and clocked out with occasional after-hours work here and there. I took days off without any concern for how the company or business was functioning without me. I can't say this is the same for everyone, though.

Answer (score 0):

The entrepreneur risks his already made investments (sometimes - all his property), the project manager risks most often only by his position in the company. The entrepreneur also determines the strategic goals for which his investments should work.

The entrepreneur hires a manager (and not vice versa) because, often, a person, possessing capital, does not always possess the necessary skills to organize the movement towards certain goals.

Answer (score 0):

### The entrepreneur originates the project and the Project Manager implements the project

Your question:

> What does an entrepreneur has that a project manager hasn't and why
>   should a project manager work under an entrepreneur in the
>   organization chart?

The entrepreneur originates the project and makes the investment decision.

The function of an entrepreneur in an organization may be performed by a start-up founder, a CEO, CXOs, EVPs, VPs and other senior leaders in large organizations with a variety of designations.

An entrepreneur may be involved in these type of broad activities that spawn one or more projects:

- Start a business: This may spawn projects such as building a product or service.
- Run a business: This may spawn projects to reduce cost, improve service and so on.
- Grow a business: This may spawn projects such as increasing capacity.

The entrepreneur may often have a gut feel for why they want to do a particular project - namely the investment needed and the returns expected. So, the entrepreneur originates a project, and hires or assigns a Project Manager (PM) to execute the project.

The PM comes in to execute such projects efficiently and effectively. Of course, it does not mean that the PM blindly implements the project. One of the major contributions of the PM may be to quantify the gut feel of the entrepreneur in the form of an ROI (Return on investment) calculation with explicit assumptions. When these numbers and assumptions are studied critically, it may or may not justify the entrepreneur's gut feel. At a minimum, it may throw a spotlight on the specific assumptions and risks and start a productive conversation.